# 3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

After updating to Android Studio 3.1 I got this error message:

[image]

The project works fine and this is mostly just a warning, so my question is what's the meaning of the warning and how can I get rid of it?

The relevant parts from gradle files:

This is my project's `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
        anko_version = '0.10.4'
        room_version = '1.0.0'
        support_version = '27.1.0'
        firebase_version = '12.0.0'
        gms_version = '12.0.0'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev' }
    }
}
```

And this is my app's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74537216 this issue is fixed in AS3.2

Comment: `Build` > `Rebuild Project` worked from me

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To solve the issue, **remove** `Instant App Provision` from the "Run Configurations" and leave only the `Gradle-Aware Make`.

```
Run -> Edit Configurations..
```

[image: My Run/Debug configurations after successful build]

I have AndroidStudio `3.1`, Gradle Plugin `3.1.0` and Kotlin library version `1.2.30`.

Comment: this actually works but any idea why it was happening and how you arrived at this solution.

Comment: and for some reason after deleting `Instant App Provisions` it always returning to its place.

Comment: Worked for me, but I'd also like to know what the issue is. Has anyone filed an issue with Google to complain about the obscure warning message?

Comment: I created an issue on the bug tracker to improve the warning message: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77356844

Comment: @PeterSamokhin can you confirm that the change is applied? I too had this issue, and `Instant App Provisions` keeps on popping up whenever a new AS window is created, despite applying the change and updating all default run configs

Comment: @AllanW cleaned local gradle caches (`~/.gradle`), all caches of project, all IDE files (`/.idea/`, `*.iml`), deleted `Instant App Provisions`, changed `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` to `kotlin-stdlib`, tried to `Invalidate & restart`. And still no sense

Comment: @PeterSamokhin try invalidating cache and restarting (under files), and if that doesn't work, try reimporting the project again rather than opening the recent project.

Comment: Another test I did was to run a build on a ci like Travis. You can also try running the gradle command via command line to ensure that the issue is related to Android studio

Comment: @AllanW tried to build & run with gradle, and all were ok. Tried to reimport (cloned from git), this also doesn't help.

Comment: Does this disable instant run?

Comment: @Caleb_Allen no, but nobody uses instant run anyway. This is for 'instant apps', not instant run

Comment: For anyone where this keeps on coming back (like @humazed), I found a fix: First go to `Run > Edit Configurations` again. Then go to `Edit Defaults` by clicking the button with the wrench icon at the top. Select `Android App` and leave only `Gradle-aware Make` like before. Hit apply.

Comment: If you're still getting this issue, it seems to have been fixed starting from AS 3.2 beta1: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/06/android-studio-32-beta-1-available.html (see "Android Studio gave superfluous warnings about folders generated by kapt.")

Comment: Android programming is becoming more and more ludicrous by the day.

Answer (score 17):

I restarted Android Studio and the problem disappeared.

**Click File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Every time I change the gradle file, I must restart Android Studio to or the problem returns.

You can also try this:

1. Re-ordered repositories to:

   ```
   mavenCentral()
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   google()
   jcenter()
   ```
2. Clearing this folder: user's **~/.gradle/caches** and deleting **app
   build folder** manually, then **clean and rebuild**.

Comment: But I still cant run my app as it will build the project before launching it.

Answer (score 7):

What fixed the issue for me:

- Change gradle plugin version to `3.1.0`
- Change Kotlin version to `1.2.30`
- Then Android studio changed gradle wrapper to version `4.4`
- Then Android studio was saying that the build tools version used was
  `27.0.3` and that I should change it to `27.0.3` so I also changed the target SDK to `27`
- I added this to my gradle.build:

  ```
  kapt {
       generateStubs = true
   }
  ```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

Here are some steps that I've followed. In my case it's fixed the issue!

**Platform modules targeting Android**
The update of the experimental multiplatform projects feature introduces support for Android platform modules. These modules should apply the corresponding plugin in the Gradle build script and can use the shared code from a common module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
// ...
// ...
```

**Kapt diagnostic locations**
As of now, kapt, the Kotlin annotation processing tool, can offer links to locations in the original Kotlin code rather than generated Java stubs as it reports errors encountered during annotation processing. You can enable this feature by adding these lines to the Gradle build script (build.gradle):

```
kapt {
    mapDiagnosticLocations = true
}
```

**Add this:**

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
```

**Don't forget the next:**

```
// Architecture Component - Room

     implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-beta1"
        kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-beta1"

      // Lifecyles, LiveData and ViewModel
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0'


 // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

// alternatively, just ViewModel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

 // alternatively, just LiveData
     implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1"
       kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

 // Room (use 1.1.0-beta1 for latest beta)
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
      kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"


// Paging
    implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha7"

        // Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"

        // Test helpers for Room
 testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0"
```

1. **Clean your project**
2. **Build and That's it!**

Add all of this, Clean your project, build and That's it! :) Let me know if this works! (If it is not working for you, I will help you with another solution)

**More Info:**  [Android Site](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html) 
*:) Let me know if it works! (If it does not work, I will
    try to help you finding a better way)*

**If you give a downVote explain why**

Comment: Adding the line `mapDiagnosticLocations = true` to `kapt` configuration works - well sometimes at least :/

Comment: @kuhnroyal  I appreaciate your feedback! Have a nice day, I keep searching for a better solution

Answer (score 5):

at android studio v3.1.2 , happen Error:

```
Folder D:\AndroidProjects\app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\debug
Folder D:\AndroidProjects\app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\release
3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause
```

because dataBinding use `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` so add

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

1. Change gradle plugin version to 3.1.2
2. Change Kotlin version to 1.2.30
3. Then Android studio changed gradle wrapper to version 4.4
4. Then Android studio was saying that the build tools version used was
   27.1.1 and that I should change it to 27.1.1 so I also changed the target SDK to 27

Answer (score 5):

What actually helped for me is adding this

```
kapt {
     generateStubs = true
}
```

into build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Try removing Instant run from settings and gradle will good to go.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some steps that i have followed and it's fixed the issue in my case.

1. First of all install kotlin plugin version to '1.2.31' and update it in build.gradle file like below.

> dependencies {
>           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
>           classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$1.2.31"
>       }

2. Clean Project.
3. Finally Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 2):

In my case none of the above solutions solved my problem, I was using 1.2.50 Kotlin version without any mention to Instant Run, and the build wasn't generating the Dagger classes, so I find out this question that solved my issue, apparently, in my situation it's an issue related to the new Kotlin version, so I downgraded to version 1.2.41 and worked fine.
By the way, I just tracked to that point because I used the Toggle View on Build screen.

1:Select the Toggle View and build your project

[image: Toggle View]

2:You're going to be able to see exactly what happened

[image: Error]

Stackoverflow question:
[Kotlin 1.2.50 asks for baseFeatureInfoDir](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50869056/2200209)

Issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110198434

Answer (score 1):

1. remove `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`
2. add `mavenCentral()` in build.gradle like:

   `allprojects {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
           google()
           jcenter() } }`
3. Sync and Clean project

Answer (score 0):

Here is the some approach how I fix this issue for my case:

> First of all update your android gradle plugin version from project build gradle file and then update your gradle version from gradle properties.
>
> Finally update your kotlin version(Mandatory) to kotlin_version = '1.2.30' or later from project build gradle file.

Now try to clean your project and build. Issue should be resolved.
Each time after build if you build again then probably issue will occur again so, just clean your project again and then build.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the Kapt annotation processor uses this directory to store Kotlin generated files. Android currently does not recognize the path by default.

[See Further Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50499671/2399352)

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer for those who **could not remove `Instant App Provision`**, because it keeps reappearing.

Build the project manually: `./gradlew assembleDebug`

It is a hotfix, but it will work (because the issue is probably related to Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-java) with kotlin in android studio.
To solve follow these steps :

1. After adding Realm to project build.gradle, Make sure your app build.gradle file is like this:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'  
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'  
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'  
   apply plugin: 'realm-android'  
   .  
   .  
   .  
   androidExtensions {  
   experimental = true
   }
   ```
2. Use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` in your app build.gradle dependencies.
3. Go to `Run -> Edit Configurations..` and remove `Instant App Provision` option.
4. Run this command in Android studio's terminal :

   ```
   gradlew assembleDebug
   ```
5. It's OK !

Note: If you see "3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause" message again, Do step 3 & 4 again.

Answer (score 0):

> Configuration on demand with Gradle 4.6 and above: If you're using
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.x or 3.1.x with Gradle 4.6 and above, you
>   should disable configuration on demand to avoid some unpredictable
>   build errors. (If you are using Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0 or higher,
>   you do not need to take any action to disable configuration on
>   demand.)
>
> Disable configuration on demand in your gradle.properties file as
>   shown below:
>
> org.gradle.configureondemand=false To disable configuration on demand
>   in the Android Studio settings, choose File > Settings (Android Studio
>
> > Preferences on Mac), select the Compiler category in the left pane, and clear the Configure on demand checkbox.
>
> In Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1 and higher, the options for enabling
>   configuration on demand have been removed.
>   Please read known issues section from below link.
>   [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues)

Answer (score 0):

Actually,I was also facing the same error.
What i did is updating my kotlin version to the [latest](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.jetbrains.kotlin%3Akotlin-gradle-plugin).
This may resolve Your problem.

Answer (score -4):

Well, I found it is because of `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`，if you delete this line in build.gradle(app), then you will build successfully...

Have no idea why this plugin results in these warnings.