# Why is "3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause" showing after updating Gradle to 3.1.0?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

After updating Gradle to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0`, in the log I now see:

> Folder
>   E:\WORK\App\car_android\carapp\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\devRelease
>
> 3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause

Comment: Does it say or imply, the cause of what exactly?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I guess it's the generateStubs = true property.

Comment: I have the same issue in Build -> Sync  messages! I am looking forward to find the solution!

Answer (score 23):

If you are receiving the warning:

> 3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause

in the build tab, it appears to be a known issue with Android Studio v3.1.x.
According to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77356844) report, It might be related to Instant App provision, but even removing that from the run/Debug configuration does not appear to resolve the issue (at least not with my installation of AS v3.1.1).

Please vote up [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74537216) issue so that it will be given more attention by the Android Studio team and hopefully a timely fix.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the Kapt annotation processor uses this directory to store Kotlin generated files.

The directory is a new generated source set, the same way you can split your source files into `src/main/java` and `src/main/kotlin`

However the Android Gradle plugin does not recognize this directory as a generated source set.

For the most part this is completely harmless as most 3rd party processors are generating `.Java` files. Kapt  writes them to the `build/generated/source/kapt` directory.

Answer (score 1):

It had worked in my project! ->

Your build.gradle Project  should look like the image below: [image]

Note: It could be little bit different if you are not using Realm and some Google Services

[image]

- Now, Let's start ->Go to you build.gradle App

**Platform modules targeting Android**
The update of the experimental multiplatform projects feature introduces support for Android platform modules. These modules should apply the corresponding plugin in the Gradle build script and can use the shared code from a common module:

1. ***You will copy this inside of your build.gradle ON THE TOP ADD IT-***

**Kapt diagnostic locations**
As of now, kapt, the Kotlin annotation processing tool, can offer links to locations in the original Kotlin code rather than generated Java stubs as it reports errors encountered during annotation processing. You can enable this feature by adding these lines to the Gradle build script (build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
// ...
```

**2. NOW ADD IT:**

```
kapt {
    mapDiagnosticLocations = true
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

**IntelliJ IDEA plugin improvements**
Kotlin 1.2.30 brings various improvements in the IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin plugin, including performance improvements, bug fixes, and new inspections and intentions.

*For some projects this is important* :
***You will copy this inside of your build.gradle-***

```
 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

*It will look like the below image*

Now we need to add the implementations inside of **dependencies{**...// **}** build.gradle:

```
// Architecture Component - Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-beta1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-beta1"

// Lifecyles, LiveData and ViewModel
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0'

// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

// alternatively, just ViewModel
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

// alternatively, just LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

// Room (use 1.1.0-beta1 for latest beta)
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"

// Paging
implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha7"

// Test helpers for LiveData
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"

// Test helpers for Room
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0"
```

*
*

1. Clean your project
2. Build it
3. That's it!

**More Info:**  [Android Site](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html) 
*:) Let me know if it works! (If it does not work, I will
    try to help you finding a better way)*

Comment: This answer would be clearer if you fixed the grammar and explained where you've copied and pasted these various blobs of blurb from.

Comment: @Boann is it look better?

Comment: *Does* it look better? No. It's extremely difficult to understand.

Comment: you saved my day. Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Android Studio issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74537216), "The root issue with Kapt is that the Kapt resolver in IDEA from JetBrains registers those folders as 'being in a invalid path'. This is a misuse of the API."

As of 6/11/2018, there's a fix in place to double-check those messages and suppress ones about paths which are actually valid.

Comment: Hi, where did you find out that there's already a fix available?

Comment: At the very end of the issue. I see there are some additional "not fixed" comments on there now.

Answer (score 0):

I delete two folder app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\debug and app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\release ("debug" and "release") and add
in gradle:

```
kapt {
        mapDiagnosticLocations = true
    }
```

then the project is sync without problem.