# Android Studio - Disable '3rd-party Gradle plug-ins' warning

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin, kapt

I am getting this error on AS after including Kotlin's annotation processor support (`kapt`) with `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in my app's `build.gradle`

```
Folder .../app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/

Folder .../app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/

3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause
```

I just need to disable this **red** warning (which is now preventing me from building the app), as I've looked into [the bug report itself](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74537216) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825951/8434188) and found out that the generated build folders from `kapt` are considered *'invalid'* to Android Studio.

I tried to uncheck some related warnings in AS's `Settings -> Inspections` but could not find the right one to disable this specific one.

If I don't include `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`, I get this runtime error:

```
Cause: app: Original kapt is deprecated. Please add "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'" to your build.gradle.
```

How may I disable this warning?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem removing Instant App Provision from
Run -> Edit Configurations

[image]

In my case Instant App Provision kept coming back from time to time, so I just kept removing it until it was fixed.