# Adding kapt to use Room causes compile errors

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I added `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to be able to use Rooms annotation proccessor:

```
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

However when I build my project I get:

```
Folder C:\Users\...\app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\debug


Folder C:\Users\...\app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\release


3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause
```

If I get rid of `kapt` and simply use `annotationProcessor` instead. The app crashes saying:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for
>   com.example..data.database.Appdatabase.
>   Appdatabase_Impl does not exist

Any ideas on how to use Room

Comment: You probably have other things that use annotationProcessor instead of kapt?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, I have the common android support libraries but the only annotation library I have is room

Comment: Any chance of databinding?

Comment: If you are using kotlin version 1.2.31 probably you will get such error. use kotlin version 1.2.30 for now.

Comment: Can you check this  for first issue ....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518223/3rd-party-gradle-plug-ins-may-be-the-cause .

Keep kapt  as that  will be the correct way .

Comment: you solve the error? I have the same

Comment: Still happening with Kotlin 1.2.51 and Andtroid Studio 3.1.3 ...

Comment: Still happening with Kotlin 1.2.51 and Andtroid Studio 3.1.4

Comment: still happening with Kotlin 1.3 ...

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue.

Go to:

> Run -> Edit Configurations -> General

At the bottom, there is window named

> Before launch: Gradle-Aware, Active  tool window

Remove

> Instant App Provision

and keep Gradle-aware Make

Answer (score 0):

I delete two folder app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\debug and app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\release ("debug" and "release") and add
in gradle:

```
kapt {
        mapDiagnosticLocations = true
    }
```

then the project is sync without problem.