# Android Studio 3.2 Canary 14 error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-architecture-components

anyone tried the new Canary build of Android studio with Navigation Editor? It does not want to run with GitHub viewer sample from Google. I mean it compiles without errors but I can not visually see what there should be with fragment navigation, only "Waiting for the build to finish" although I tried to build the project like 20 times

Here is the screenshot: [image]

As you can see, it is from Android architecture samples, the GitHub browser one. Here is a link to it:

[GitHub Browser Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) You just open it and let it compile

It is not an error with gradle compilation as you can see bellow the red lines, the problem is the navigation editor introduced in Canary 14

Comment: yep, same problem here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518223/3rd-party-gradle-plug-ins-may-be-the-cause)

Comment: This is a problem from me too. Can view other xml files from layout just fine. Everything from navigation has the same thing your screen shot shows.

Comment: Found this ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79652974 tracking it.

Comment: For a temporary workaround see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201356/navigation-drawer-issue-not-showing-layout-preview/50221647#50221647

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - you need to update your Canary build - Currently 3.2 canary 18 as of time of writing. Also, if Mac user, running HighSierra - ensure that your preview version of Android Studio is stored with the /Applications folder - otherwise you will not have write access to update AS. Issue solved

Answer (score 0):

If you have the test dependency 
    `androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"`
try removing it. Then do Invalidate caches and restart.