# Kotlin 1.2.50 asks for baseFeatureInfoDir

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

When I switch in an Android project with

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'`

to

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50"`

I run into

> What went wrong:
>
> > Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':detector:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> >
> > Directory '~/project/build/intermediates/feature_data_binding_base_feature_info/debug/dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug/out' specified for property 'annotationProcessorOptionProviders$kotlin_gradle_plugin.$0.$0.baseFeatureInfoDir' does not exist.
> >     Directory '~/project/build/intermediates/feature_data_binding_base_feature_info/debug/dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug/out' specified for property 'databinding.baseFeatureInfoDir' does not exist.

with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'` it works properly

Comment: On 1.2.50, feature_data_binding_base_feature_info is not generated. You can revert the version to 1.2.41, build, update to 1.2.50 and run ( which is a drag so better to leave at 1.2.41 until issue is fixed ). It's already reported in Bug Tracker, you can track it on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110198434

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well, glad it's not a unique issue to my machine.

Answer (score 9):

This issue will be fixed in Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0-beta02

Change-Id: I7b7977845e5dee13240f2b0422ccc270513cade9