# How to use Data Binding and Kotlin in Android Studio 3.1.4?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kapt

I got error Kotlin kapt 3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause. I have added plugin for kotlin-kapt and updated my gradle properties with android.databindingV3=true.But I still got error 3rd-part Gradle plugins.
How to fix this?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


    android {
       ...
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

        //Room
        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
        kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

        ///Lifecycles, LiveData and ViewModel
        kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'

        // ViewModel and LiveData
        implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

        // ViewModel
        implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

        // LiveData
        implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1"
        kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

        annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
        androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1"
        androidTestImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
```

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518223/3rd-party-gradle-plug-ins-may-be-the-cause (or apparently to update to an up-to-date AS3.2.x) ?

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: My error is Kotlin kapt 3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause and I have followed every step in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518223/3rd-party-gradle-plug-ins-may-be-the-cause. But still have the same error in ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50' .

Comment: If you are referring to the folder generation errors that appear in the right but do not affect the build or app running, that is normal. Everyone gets that. It has to do with the runtime update library in your edit configuration. Confirm that is what you are talking about and I will give you the details to help remove it if it bothers you.

Comment: Solved it and I had to update gradle file.